# I have to evaluate <div> tag according to if-else for the value coming from controller class

Tags: jsp

i have to evaluate this div tag from the value coming from controller class
How do we do it without javascript .
If value is coming then it should go to this tag and if it's null then it will not evaluate this tag and also i have to print that value

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: <div class="panel-body">
      <% String roll=(String)request.getParameter("roll");
         String cssClass="";
         if(null!=roll){
          cssClass=" alert-danger";
          
         }
      %>
      <div class="row alert <%= cssClass %>"
        style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">
      It should evaluate the tag below based on above condition but on reloading page it's giving null i dont want null to display.
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10"><%=roll%></div>

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSTL tag libraries to create conditional HTML using JSP underneath. Here's a quick reference: https://code.google.com/p/dlcode/downloads/detail?name=jstl-quick-reference.pdf.

In your case you could go with something similar:

```
<c:choose> 
   <c:when test="${not empty yourControllerVar}">
       <c:out value="${yourControllerVar}"/>
       <div>
         //your div code
       </div> 
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
       // do something else, without the div
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: I am trying but still am on same phase

Comment: Are you accessing your variable using EL? Like this : ${param.yourRequestVariable} ?